# Можно ли сказать "приличная страна"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли сказать: "Приличная страна"? Если нет, то почему? Если да, то можно ли так сказать в деловом разговоре?

Answer (score 1):

Слово "приличный" имеет много значений и употребляется довольно часто.

[**Приличный**](http://endic.ru/academic/Prilichn-46164.html) (МАС)
**1.**
Соответствующий приличиям; пристойный.
||
Вполне достойный, порядочный.
**2.**
*кому-чему. устар.* Подобающий, подходящий, соответствующий.
**3.** *разг.*
Достаточно хороший, удовлетворительный.
||
Достаточно большой, значительный; порядочный.

В толковом словаре Ефремовой пометка "разг." отсутствует.
"Приличная страна" — так можно говорить (все зависит от контекста и вкладываемого смысла). Во всяком случае, журналисты и политики разных уровней так говорят.

*Вейонис: Латвия — [приличная страна](https://lv.sputniknews.ru/politics/20180425/8097700/Prezident-Latvii-Putin-pozdravlen-vse-porjadke.html) и поздравила Путина, все в порядке*
*Медведев: Каждая [приличная страна](https://news.finance.ua/ru/news/-/298929/medvedev-kazhdaya-prilichnaya-strana-imeet-svoyu-offshornuyu-zonu) имеет свою оффшорную зону*
*Подведем итоги: ниже Эстонии Португалия, Греция и еще много-много [приличных стран](https://rus.postimees.ee/937898/podvedem-itogi-nizhe-estonii-portugaliya-greciya-i-eshche-mnogo-mnogo-prilichnyh-stran)*
*Спецпредставитель США призвал Сирию «вести себя как приличная страна»*

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!